A stock trader that falls in love with an horoscope writer
I am looking for this movie. The main action turns around a stock broker that reads into a journal, about his horoscope, something like "abandon the Old (italian: Vecchi) and engage New Horizons". When reading this over the phone to his trader colleague, his friend interprets it as an order to sell shares of a company named Vecchi, and in return to buy shares of a company called New Horizons.
The transaction is highly successful, since Vecchi is exposed as fraudulent, and New Horizons receives some very good news, short after the transaction.
The trader is so impressed that he starts looking for the horscope writer, who turns out to be a beautiful lady, and finally they marry. During his quest for her, he is constantly followed by a rival trader, who just wants to learn the secret.
In the end, it proves that the horoscope was right just by pure chance, the lady had no special divination skills, as she confesses to him.
The last scene is something like the trader and his wife sponsoring charity and he saying something on the lines: "X millions may seem a lot of money, but it is not so much when your wife wants to do so much charity".
I think that the actress (and, possibly, the movie and its cast) are South American.
I am looking for the movie's title. Thanks in advance.
